# Complex sorting of an array of objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object, forum

I need to sort an array of objects for a forum program with multiple comparisons.  Each post (main thread or reply) is an instance of a class Post.  I need to sort the main threads by their timeLastChanged property (for bumping) and then sort the replies underneath them by their timeStarted property (oldest first).  My goal was to sort the array in the exact order it would be displayed in the forum table.  Simply, sorted and displayed like this:

```
- Main thread
   - Reply
      - Reply
   - Reply
   - Reply
      - Reply
         - Reply
- Main thread
```

etc.
I've looked at usort and the like but I can't figure how the comparison functions would work to do this.  Oh, and each object has a property isReply that is set to 0 if it isn't a reply and set to the thread ID of the post it is a reply of, if it is a reply.  Each object has a property TID which is its thread ID (unique). I also have a property called numReplies that shows how many direct replies a message has (and then, of course, replies would have their own numReplies that show how many replies are assigned to that reply, etc).

I've got the displaying part down and the grabbing the info from the database, I'm just not sure of the most efficient way of sorting it.  Thanks for any help.

Edit: here is the code I have that starts the class, I excluded the part where I grab the data from the database, but just know that all the applicable instances of Post are assigned to their respective array of objects (replies are in replyObjs, mains are in mainsObjs, etc):

```
class Category {

    public $title;
    public $majCatID;
    public $catID;
    public $modLevel;
    public $postingLevel;
    public $hostedByUID;
    public $order;
    public $shortName;
    public $info;
    public $stickyObjs;
    public $mainsObjs;
    public $replyObjs;
    public $orderedObjs;
    private $database;

    public function __construct($catID) {
        $this->database = new TBDatabase;
        $result = $this->database->getIntRow(CAT_TABLE, 'catID', $catID);
        $row = $this->database->fetchAssoc($result);
        $this->title = $row['title'];
        $this->majCatID = $row['majCatID'];
        $this->catID = $row['catID'];
        $this->modLevel = $row['modLevel'];
        $this->postingLevel = $row['postingLevel'];
        $this->hostedByUID = $row['hostedByUID'];
        $this->order = $row['order'];
        $this->shortName = $row['shortName'];
        $this->info = $row['info'];
        }
    public function sortPosts() {
        $table = $this->shortName."_threads";
        $this->getStickyObjs();
        $numStickies = count($this->stickyObjs);
        $this->getMainObjs();
        $numMains = count($this->mainsObjs);
        $this->getReplyObjs();
        $numReplies = count($this->replyObjs);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting an array of objects, so the [PHP array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) are not really going to help you unless you want to sort by the array keys.

You'll have to loop over the array of objects and access the objects properties and rebuild your array in the order you want. Without seeing some of your code, it's not really possible to give more detail.

As you are pulling the data from the database, it's probably best to do the sorting there.

If you have a class "Article" then it can have a method "getComments" which may do the database calls directly or involve some other classes/methods to retrieve the comments for that article. Though, sorting in the database is probably the best all round, as you may as well sort them while retrieving them. That's what databases do.

Here is an air code example. It's a recursive function. So be careful.

```
public function getComments($id, $sort)
{
    $sorted = array();
    $comments = $this->getChildren($id, $sort); // make getChildren return null if no children records.
    if (!is_null($comments) && count($comments) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($comments as $comment)
        {
            $sorted[$comment['id']] = $comment;
            $sorted[$comment['id']]['children'] = $this->getComments($comment['id'], $sort);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $sorted = $comments;
    }
    return $sorted;
}
```

Comment: I'll edit the question with my current code minus the failed attempts at sorting it myself.

Comment: I don't see any code. Are you coding in PHP? Do you have a property "parentID" or some such thing?

Comment: I just posted the code I have so far, it's just a basic class start and some database calls so far, the sorting attempts from earlier I left out.  Yes, I have a parentID property, it is called isReply which is set to 0 if it isn't a reply and if it is a reply, it is set to the thread ID (TID) of the direct parent message.

Comment: By the way, the "getStickyObjs" and "getMainsObjs" calls are just functions I left out because they just simply grab the messages from the database according to if they are a sticky, main, or reply and instantiate a Post object for each based on their info and apply it to one of the three arrays of objects (stickyObjs, mainsObjs, or replyObjs).

Comment: @Adam: So class Category is 1 comment? What does "Category" represent in relation to "comments". I think you may want to think this through again. I edited in my answer, you probably want to do sorting in the database. I'll add some more detail to my answer.

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that - category represents a forum category so on a programming forum it might be "PHP Coding Help" or "mySQL Help" etc, then a post object is any form of post whether it be a main thread or a reply or a reply of a reply or a sticky, etc.

Comment: Are you saying it might be easier to sort them into the database correctly as I go instead of sorting them later during processing?

Comment: Yes, it's generally better to sort in the DB. You can have a method that accepts some parameters for how you want to sort them. Then you can abstract those details away into a method or even another class.

Comment: That might actually be much easier, sorting as they are posted, it would be easy to grab the direct parent and then insert the row in between the last reply that shares the parent thread ID and the next set of stuff.  Now I have to research how to insert a row in between two existing rows based on parameters in mysql :)

Comment: One more thing regarding your class structure, you might want to do have an "Article" class with a "category" property. Then you have a "category" class and it's properties: description, title, etc.

Comment: You don't have to insert a row in between anything. You just need to have the correct SQL query. You might have to do more than one db call. For example, get all parents sort by createDate. Then get all children of those parents sort by modifyDate, and build up your array like this.

Comment: Gotcha, then I will just have to insert into an array between two keys, which is actually possible.  Or, I might be looking at the problem in a backward way.  I was trying to get a fully ordered array of objects to list in the exact order they should be displayed but I guess I could go for displaying them as I sort?

Comment: @Adam, I've updated with an example. It's just the basic idea. You'll have to refine and test it to make it sort the way you want. It's a recursive function that will continue to get the children until none are returned (null). Hope that helps.